# What is the norm of the operator $Af(x) = \cos(x)f(x)$.

Tags: functional-analysis

Imagine you are given the following condition:
$$
a < 0 < b
$$
And you have the following operator:
$$
L^2([a, b]) \to L^2([a, b]) \\ \; \\
f(x) \to \cos({x})f(x)
$$
If you want to bound the norm of the operator:
$$
\Vert Tf(x)\Vert  = \int_a^b |\cos(x)f(x)|^2dx \leq \max\{ |\cos(x)|^2\}\int_a^b |f(x)|^2dx \leq\int_a^b |f(x)|^2 dx= \Vert f(x)\Vert 
$$

$$
\Vert Tf(x)\Vert  \leq \Vert f(x)\Vert  \; \; \Rightarrow \; \; \Vert T\Vert  \leq 1
$$
But how would you find the exact norm of $T$. I'm stuck. Any Hint?

Comment: The operator norm can be given by $\sup\{\Vert T f\Vert\ ~:~\Vert f\Vert \leq 1\}$. But this doesn't help much.

Comment: You can't have an $x$ outside the integral Replace the max with $1$ before moving it outside.

Comment: More generally: for the norm for a "multiplication map" $f \mapsto \phi f$, the norm is the "essential supremum" of $|\phi|$.